# How to translate and rotate chairs around a table

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

I'd like to evenly devide a n number of chairs around a round table.
Tried several solutions that involve animation an object around a circle, but I'm not able to convert any of them to a solution for my problem.
(http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dFctW/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Cu6Zv/1/)

The project I'm working on involves a chosen amount of chairs that need to be devided among a chosen amount of tables. I managed to sort of build a prototype, but the chairs are not evenly devided and not rotated toward the center of the table.

[image]

```
var step = 360 / chairs;
for(var count = 0; count < chairs; count++){
  angle += Math.acos(1-Math.pow(step/radius,2)/2);

  var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);

  ctx.rect(x-5,y-5,10,10);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxv4zbdd/1/) of what I've got so far.

Hopefully someone can explain me how to:

- Translate the chairs evenly around the circle
- Rotate each chair to line up with the table (pointed towards the center of the table)
- Perhaps explain the math behind it, so I can understand what it's doing and how it could be adapted if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the code for online loading spinner generators they should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost at right track with the code. Simply use radians instead and drop the acos line:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0;
var chairs = 6;
var cx = c.width>>1, cy = c.height>>1, radius = (c.height>>1)-10;
var step = Math.PI * 2 / chairs;

for(var count = 0; count < chairs; count++){
  var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  ctx.rect(x-5,y-5,10,10);
  angle += step;
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Now, all the chairs will face the same direction. If you want to rotate them so they face center of tables it's perhaps easier to use transforms instead of manually calculating the position:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0;
var chairs = 6;
var cx = c.width>>1, cy = c.height>>1, radius = (c.height>>1)-10;
var step = Math.PI * 2 / chairs;

// translate to center
ctx.translate(cx, cy);

for(var count = 0; count < chairs; count++){
  // rotate around center (0,0)
  ctx.rotate(step);
  
  // draw using radius as offser on x-axis only
  ctx.rect(radius -5,-5,10,10);
  ctx.rect(radius -5, -1, 4,2);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I managed to get the devision of the chair working for my prototype using the code above. But I do have some trouble facing the chair in the right direction. It seems that the translate and rotate are causing some problems. Am I supposed to combine the two snippets as it seems that the last snippit is doing the job?

Comment: @RobinHermans what would be the right direction? just use one of examples. The latter rotates the entire context which is why you can draw the same chair in the same position, and therefor having them face towards center of table. You may want to reset the transform afterwards though (`ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`). If you're using drawImage the chair must be designed to point towards right, ie. the back of chair in this case. Otherwise you would have to add a local transform as well in the position the chair is drawn. Let me know if this is what you mean.

Comment: I think I been to hasty on the last comment. On second attempt to implement it in my prototype I managed to get it working. Huge thanks.

Comment: @RobinHermans ah ok, no problem. Important thing is that it works :)

Comment: I'm happy with how the result turned out.
http://i.imgur.com/72UCnHF.png

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, try changing:

```
var step = 360 / chairs;
```

to

```
var step = 360 / (chairs + 1);
```